# How to remove sliding effect and sharp transition during the animation

Tags: animation, mixamo

I tried to increase the animation action time and combine some animations by using graph editor in different ways, but I got a sliding effect when I tried to increase animation time and I got sharp transition when I tried to combine different animations among themselves. How to fix it?

Videos:

1. https://rumble.com/v3xxzba-november-26-2023.html
2. https://rumble.com/v3xxzkg-november-26-2023.html

Files: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1kb8xYDPts3Fdu1V3lSjwDVREctDK5cMZ?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.